# What are some ways to restrict the decimal places in JSON Schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I am trying to store decimal numbers with restricted number of decimal places in my JSON data, and initially, I wanted to do it using strings. However, the schema does not support this. So as of right now, I am restricted to using this:

```
{"type": "number", "multipleOf" : 0.1} <- 1 decimal place
{"type": "number", "multipleOf" : 0.01} <- 2 decimal places
```

This works fine in dev, but I know from first hand experience how quickly floats can break down in actual applications. So my first choice is still finding some way to store them as strings in my data. Is this possible with the current implementation of JSON Schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the previous answer, If you are happy to represent the number as a string, you can use a regex pattern.

The below will restrict a number to 15sf (potentially useful if you are concerned about floating point expressibility):

```
{
   "type": "string",
   "pattern": "^(?!(?:.*?[1-9]){15,})([-+]?\\s*\\d+\\.?\\d*?)$"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not something that is possible with JSON Schema for numbers.
If you can represent your number as a string, you can use regex in the JSON Schema to check this sort of thing.

Look up the `pattern` key word.